# problems with php in_array

Tags: php, arrays

Hey guys got an issue with the in_array not returning true.

my code is as follows:

```
if ( in_array( 'item_name', $this->conditions ) ) {
        print "test";
}
```

this is just a test code.
the $this->conditions is set in someplace else in the files and it looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [operator] => 
        [property] => item_name
        [logic] => contains
        [value] => the age
    )

)
```

its not printing the "test";
what am i doing wrong ?

var_dump added below:

```
array (size=2)
0 => 
array (size=4)
  'operator' => string '' (length=0)
  'property' => string 'item_name' (length=9)
  'logic' => string 'contains' (length=8)
  'value' => string 'the age' (length=7)
1 => 
array (size=4)
  'operator' => string 'or' (length=2)
  'property' => string 'item_name' (length=9)
  'logic' => string 'ends' (length=4)
  'value' => string 'malouf' (length=6)
```

Comment: Do a var_dump of $this->conditions to see exactly what it contains (e.g. no spaces or other invisible characters)

Comment: `$this->conditions` is an object you can verify using `is_object()` function. `$this->conditions[0]` will do for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a nested array. Try this :

```
foreach ($this->conditions as $arr) {

    if ( in_array( 'item_name', $arr ) ) {
       print "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: the issue is the conditions can have multiple arrays

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
foreach($this->conditions as  $condition){
 if(in_array( 'item_name',  $condition))
     echo 'test';
};
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

[PHP DOC :](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
in_array — Checks if a value exists in an array
```

`in_array()` wont return true because there is no value `"item_name"`. You have to extract the inner array first. This : `in_array( 'item_name', $this->conditions[0])` will return `true`